# Convert HtmlNode to Xpath

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I use C# and HtmlAgilityPack. If i have an any html node string, example:

**tag name1="value1" name2="value2; value3"...**

I want to convert it to xpath string: 
**//tag[@name1='value1' and @name2='value2; value3' and...]**

when i don't know what are those **tag('id' or 'class' or 'td'...)**; **names('href' or 'src' or 'style'...)**; **values**.

Do I have to split string to get value of '**tag**', '**name1**', '**value1**', '**name2**', '**value2; value3**' by myself or use other shorter ways?

---

You can help me by converting to LinQ but I think LinQ is more difficult than Xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can combine `HtmlNode.Name` and list of attribute-value pairs into XPath string as follow :** (implemented as extension method)

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToXPath(this HtmlNode node)
    {
        var attributes = node.Attributes.Any() ? "[" + string.Join(" and ", node.Attributes.Select(o => "@" + o.Name + "='" + o.Value + "'")) + "]" : "";
        var xpath = "//" + node.Name + attributes;
        return xpath;
    }
}
```

**Example usage :**

```
var raw = @"<div>
<span id='span_1' class='baz'>foo</span>
<span id='span_2'>bar</span>
</div>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(raw);
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.ToXPath());
}
```

**output :**

```
//div
//span[@id='span_1' and @class='baz']
//span[@id='span_2']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for quick answer but your code has error. I think maybe **node.Attributes.Select(o => "@" + o.Name + "='" + o.Value + "'")** need **.ToArray()**. And it works :D

Comment: hi, can you answer this question? We have to go through all our angular files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63290489/selenium-convert-data-qa-tags-to-c-sharp-xpath-getters

Comment: just gave thumbs up on question and answer,